# I am getting this error while clicking on a sub menu which goes to another desktop UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, desktop-application

```
    public List<Evaluation> GetAllEvaluations()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Evaluation";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand.CommandText = query;
            SqlConnection.Open();
            IDataReader data = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            List<Evaluation> evaluations = new List<Evaluation>();
            while (data.Read())
            {
                Evaluation anEvaluation = new Evaluation
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt16(data["Id"]),
                    Grade = data["Grade"].ToString()
                };
                evaluations.Add(anEvaluation);
            }
            return evaluations;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (SqlConnection != null && SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                SqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Grade

Comment: Please specify what type `data` is.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `data` either doesn't have `Id` or `Grade` defined... So it returns "out of range", because it isn't included in your variable. Try to debug your code and find out why it's so.